# how to arrange pandas dataframe column in descending order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `tsp_data_unique` like this..

```
      order_id    quant_bought    Clusters
 0       537            2         Cluster 2
 1       540            1         Cluster 10
 2       541            1         Cluster 4
 3       542            2         Cluster 2
 4       543            2         Cluster 2
 5       545            3         Cluster 2
 6       546            2         Cluster 2
 7       548            3         Cluster 1
 8       549            3         Cluster 6
 9       550            4         Cluster 2
 10      553            1         Cluster 11
 11      555            1         Cluster 1
 12      556            1         Cluster 1
 13      557            1         Cluster 3
 14      584            3         Cluster 2
 15      586            3         Cluster 2
 16      587            3         Cluster 5
 17      588            1         Cluster 7
 18      589            1         Cluster 10
 19      590            1         Cluster 9
 20      591            2         Cluster 2
 21      592            3         Cluster 2
 22      593            1         Cluster 2
 23      594            7         Cluster 8
 24      595            3         Cluster 2
 25      596            1         Cluster 1
 26      608            2         Cluster 2
 27      609            4         Cluster 2
```

And the second dataframe as `df`

```
      Clusters                                           order_id
0    Cluster 1                               [548, 555, 556, 596]
1   Cluster 10                                         [540, 589]
2   Cluster 11                                              [553]
3    Cluster 2  [537, 542, 543, 545, 546, 550, 584, 586, 591, ...
4    Cluster 3                                              [557]
5    Cluster 4                                              [541]
6    Cluster 5                                              [587]
7    Cluster 6                                              [549]
8    Cluster 7                                              [588]
9    Cluster 8                                              [594]
10   Cluster 9                                              [590]
```

Now I want to arrange the `order_id's` of `Cluster 2` of `df` dataframe `Clusters` column in descending order by `quant_bought` column in 1st dataframe.

I am doing following in python.

```
 p  =  df.order_id[df['Clusters'] == 'Cluster 2']
 a = tsp_data_unique['order_id'].isin(p.values[0])
 b = tsp_data_unique['quant_bought'][a]   
 b.sort() 
 b = b[::-1]
 p = tsp_data_unique['order_id'][b.index]
 list_p = p.values.tolist()
 df.order_id[df['Clusters'] == 'Cluster 2'] = list_p
```

When I assign the descending ordered list to `Cluster 2` in `df` it gives me an error

`ValueError: Length of replacements must equal series length`

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think work with list in column is not easy.

If `index` value, where `df['Clusters'] == 'Cluster 2'` is only one, you can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
p  =  df.order_id[df['Clusters'] == 'Cluster 2']
a = tsp_data_unique['order_id'].isin(p.values[0])
b = tsp_data_unique['quant_bought'][a]  
#replace sort to sort_values, because future warning 
b.sort_values(inplace=True) 
b = b[::-1]
p = tsp_data_unique['order_id'][b.index]
list_p = p.values

print list_p
[550 586 584 545 591 546 543 542 537]

idx = df[df['Clusters'] == 'Cluster 2'].index[0]

print idx
1

df['order_id'].iloc[idx] =  list_p

print df.iloc[idx]
Clusters                                        Cluster 2
order_id    [550, 586, 584, 545, 591, 546, 543, 542, 537]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
In [25]: tsp_data_unique
Out[25]: 
   order_id  quant_bought  cluster
0       537             2        4
1       540             1        3
2       541             5        4
3       542             1        4
4       544             2        3

In [26]: df = tsp_data_unique.sort_values(['cluster', 'order_id'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('cluster')['order_id'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
cluster
3         [544, 540]
4    [542, 541, 537]
Name: order_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I want to sort `Cluster 2 order_id` in descending order depending upon `quant_bought` in first dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to assign a list as an element in a data frame. However it expects a single value in the list like `[ 5 ]`. Since the length of the list you are assigning is `> 1` and the length of the value you are trying to replace is just 1, there is a mismatch in length and Python throws an error.

To resolve this, try using your list as the first element of another list, as shown below:

```
df.order_id[df['Clusters'] == 'Cluster 2'] = [ list_p ]
```